# How does a DM announce loot?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, treasure

Say the party finds an altar, and laying on it are a Wand of Wonder and a lapis lazuli worth 10 gold. How much information does the party get? As DM, do I say "you find a strange wand and a blue gem", and the party must find a Wizard to cast Identify to learn more about the wand, as well as a jeweler to appraise the gem? Do you give values to things like art objects and gems when they are found?

Comment: Are you the DM or a player?

Comment: Unfortunately, every DM is going to be different on this. And even with a single DM, they can change how they describe things every time. It will also depend on if you're playing homebrew or Adventure League (at the time of this comment, players can't find items of monetary values, so gems, jewels, and gold are not just laying around).

Comment: Unfortunately, survey-type questions like this one that ask "how do people handle this" are not a great fit for RPG.SE, because every answer is equally valid; there's no way to choose a single "best" answer. It might better to edit your question to focus on asking about unintended consequences or pros and cons of a certain approach.

Comment: Thanks - didn't realize this was a "no wrong way to eat a Reese's" situation.